# JavaScript RegExp what was matched

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and I need to find out what was matched in the string. For example:

```
var txt = "Hello world!";
txt.replace(/[a-h]/gi, '<span>' + TEXT_MATCHED + '</span');
```

I would like the output to be... `<span>H</span><span>e</span>llo worl<span>d</span>!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
var txt = "Hello world!";
txt.replace(/([a-h])/gi, "<span>$1</span>");
```

(step 1: group the matched stuff using brackets. step 2: use $1 for the first matched group)

Comment: It does work sometimes, but I'm not entirely sure what makes it work and what breaks it.

Comment: Ooops, it does work - sorry! I think the reason I thought it didn't, is I forgot to add the () to my regex, and of course then it doesn't work.